# MySQL IF Statements in Query issues

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query that I am trying to execute. It is the starting point for a query required to run a report:

```
SET @fname = 'Bob';
SET @blah = 0;

SELECT CASE WHEN @fname IS NULL THEN @blah = 1 ELSE @blah END;


    IF (@blah > 0) THEN
       SELECT * FROM mytable
    END IF;
```

Something is apparently wrong with my syntax but I cannot figure it out. I've written other queries using IF statements without issue. This will not run in either SQLyog or Workbench. It says there is a sytax error on "IF" with or without the parens, doesn't matter.

All I need is the ability to evaluate a variable/input parameter in the IF statement.

Any help is appreciated. *NOTE* - the SELECT CASE may not be necessary if I can get the IF to evaluate parameters properly but I was trying any possible solutions.

Thanks

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve, let start from there first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use IF-THEN construction only inside BEGIN...END clause, which can be used only in procedures, functions, triggers, and events. It is impossible to use it in a simple script.

For your case I'd suggest this one -

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE @blah > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. There needs to be a procedure or some form of script that needs to be executed given the case.
2. `CALL` procedure method needs to be initiated in the report datasource in such scenarios

   Script can be written in following way: (Note: PROCEDURE can have parameters as required)

   ```
   DELIMITER ?
   CREATE PROCEDURE XYZ()
   BEGIN
   SET @fname = 'Bob';
   SET @blah = 1;

   SELECT CASE WHEN @fname IS NULL THEN  @blah = 0 ELSE @blah END;
   IF (@blah > 0) THEN
   SELECT * from mytable;
   END IF;
   END ?
   DELIMITER;
   ```

   You can then pass the `CALL XYZ()` with or without parameters as required to your datasource or where you would pass your query to be executed for generating report.

Following works properly on MySQL Workbench. `SELECT CASE` query can be removed from the above procedure if not required.

Answer (score 0):

I see issue with else statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @fname IS NULL THEN @blah = 1 END;
```

Comment: I dont have to set blah to anything, it can just be itself. Works fine with MSSQL so I wouldn't expect that to be an issue here since I set blah at the top.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Using procedure getting result as per requirement

drop procedure abc;
DELIMITER // 
create procedure abc() 
begin 
declare fname varchar(10);
declare blah int; 

set fname = 'Bob'; 
set blah = 0;

if(fname IS not NULL) then
       SELECT * from studmaster; 
end if; 

end //
DELIMITER ;

//--comment--> for execute procedure
call abc();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps you much, but you can use if statement in an sql query

```
Select Blah.name,sum(Blah.quan) as SumofQuan,  IF(Blah.descr LIKE '%searchterm%', "FOUND", IF(Blah.descr ="x", "x", "The Rest")) as New_DECRIPTION
```

Answer (score -1):

I understand more of SQL SERVER, then it may be that my answer is not very helpful, but anyway here is my help:

Try changing the code snippet below,

```
SELECT @blah = (CASE WHEN @fname IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE @blah END)
```

Answer (score -1):

In my view when using Sql server i found that the variable cannot assigned a value without declaring it..

I think you must have done as:

```
declare @fname nvarchar(50)
declare @blah int
```

then you must assign value to the variabl..

```
SET @fname = 'Bob'
SET @blah = 0

SELECT CASE WHEN @fname IS NULL THEN @blah = 1 ELSE @blah END;


IF (@blah > 0) THEN
   SELECT * FROM mytable
END IF;
```